# Mounting instance storage corrupting ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems, mount

I'm trying to mount two instance storages in my ec2 instance and before creating an AMI, I just want to try it's mounting those storages at the right mount point. But as soon as I stop and start my instance after mounting, I'm unable to connect. Looks like it's unable to boot even though ec2 console shows they are running.

I get this right after I create my instance(i2.2xlarge):

```
[root@xxxxx ec2-user]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   300G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   300G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0 745.2G  0 disk
xvdc    202:32   0 745.2G  0 disk
```

Then I format and mount those two to two different location.

```
[root@xxxx ec2-user]# mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdc
[root@xxxx ec2-user]# mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdc
```

Here is my fstab:

```
#
LABEL=/     /           ext4    defaults,noatime  1   1
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0   0
sysfs       /sys        sysfs   defaults        0   0
proc        /proc       proc    defaults        0   0
/dev/xvdb   /media/ephemeral0   ext4    defaults,nofail,comment=cloudconfig 0   2
/dev/xvdc   /media/ephemeral1   ext4    defaults,nofail,comment=cloudconfig 0   2
```

After I mount them, I get this which I want at the end:

```
[root@xxxxxx ec2-user]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      493G  1.2G  491G   1% /
devtmpfs         30G   68K   30G   1% /dev
tmpfs            31G     0   31G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb       734G   69M  697G   1% /media/ephemeral0
/dev/xvdc       734G   69M  697G   1% /media/ephemeral1
```

At this point, when I want to stop and start the instance, I'm unable to connect that instance. I know those two are ephemeral storage and I don't care it's content. But I want to recreate several similar instances like this, so before creating an AMI, I just wanted to test it to see after I restart this instance, it keeps mount configuration.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is a major problem while working with paritioning. The root cause of problem is SElinux which is refusing SSH connection

**Here are the steps which will solve your issue :**

**Step 1 :** Create the volume in AWS Console and attach it to instance. (Assuming you know this already!)

**Step 2 :** By default it is always mounted on `/dev/xvdc`, please create the partition using fdisk and confirm the lsblk output, it should look like below:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/xvdc
```

**Use options `N` to create a new partition and all the defaults for creating 1 full partition for entire volume and option `W` to write the partition in the filesystem**

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdc    202:80   0  20G  0 disk 
└─xvdc1 202:81   0  20G  0 part
```

*All the work ahead would be done on this xvdfc partition, make sure you are NOT using /dev/xvdc anywhere.

**Step 3 : Format the below partition using**

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdc1
```

**Step 4: Make the entry in fstab as below:**

```
/dev/xvdf1   /var       ext4    defaults,noatime,nofail 0   2
```

Hope that helps :)

Here are some links that might help :

[STEPS TO CREATE SEPARATE /VAR PARTITION ON EBS VOLUME AWS](http://bhargavamin.com/how-to-do/create-separate-var-partition-ebs-volume-aws/)

[CREATE ROOT SWAP AND LVM PARTITION ON EBS VOLUME (AWS)](http://bhargavamin.com/how-to-do/create-root-swap-lvm-partition-ebs-volume-aws/)